# Cannot start FileZilla from linux command line

Tags: linux, filezilla

I have installed filezilla on ubuntu, which I need to run from the command line. But when I try to run it showing eg. help or version I get:

```
~$ filezilla -h
Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
~$ filezilla -v
Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

As I understand a commandline interface should exists for linux:

http://blog.freshshare.com/how-to/how-to-transfer-files-with-filezilla-from-command-line.htm

Comment: What does "echo $DISPLAY" say? Are you trying to run Filezilla via SSH?

Comment: On my debian sid work box (yes, I know) I get this;
`$ filezilla -v FileZilla 3.5.3, compiled on 2012-06-29` No output actually attaches to the X-server, though I have one running. What happens here if you artificially set DISPLAY=:1 or something similar and try it again?

Comment: echo $DISPLAY gives nothing, but why do I need to set the display when running from commandline/headless/without gui? "set DISPLAY=:1" does not help - it still gives empty output when doing echo $DISPLAY

Comment: Try it like: `DISPLAY=:1 filezilla -v`

Comment: Still gives: Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
I have tried to do "export DISPLAY=:1" but I still get the above error - but now it actually has a value when I echo it.

Answer (score 1):

Many GUI apps have command line *options* but this does not mean you can use them without X running.  The command line options are there for launchers and menus to use.

Even if you figure out the DISPLAY setting properly, it's just going to launch the GUI.

If you want an FTP application that doesn't require a GUI, try `lftp`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable server access control program for X by invoking  `xhost +` in your normal user terminal. It will grant any user to connect to X-server. Once you are done, just make sure to restrict it by `xhost -` since its enable by default for security reasons.

Comment: Maybe I am missing the big picture here but is a X-server not only required for running gui apps? I just need to run the command line version of filezilla. I have tried "xhost +" which gives: "~$ xhost +
xhost:  unable to open display ":1"

Comment: `xhost + : Turns off access control (all remote/local hosts will have access to X server)` When every I run into issues like ` Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0` I turn the access control off, and it works.

Comment: and make sure you have gtk installed on your machine